# Loss of data after restarting Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, output, jupyter

I restarted Jupyter notebook from the terminal, and after waiting for the kernel to be successfully reconnected, I wanted to run a new cell below a previously ran program. While my new cell required functions defined in above cells and data output previously ran. The pre-ran program took a long time to output the data and results so I don't want to rerun it. Currently, the cell is still loading to run as it reveals this `[*]` sign.

Referencing to previous experiences that after I restarted Jupyter, and reloaded a certain program file, I'll always lose my previously ran data, as the output of a new cell will often prompt me to define certain functions that I previously defined in above cells. So, I'm afraid that I already lost the data I previously trained in this current program.

Example of a previous program that had lost predefined function when running a new cell:

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>   ----> 1 interp.plot_confusion_matrix(figsize=(10,10), dpi=60)
>
> NameError: name 'interp' is not defined

For my current running cell, I restarted Jupyter and reconnected to kernel but I haven't reloaded the program file. So, Jupyter didn't report errors about missing function or variable definitions.

Is there a way for me quickly output the cell from the preran program?

Can anyone provide some strategies to save the data ran in Jupyter instead of having to rerun everything when re-accessing the file?

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: [Prevent Reprocessing with HDFStore](https://realpython.com/fast-flexible-pandas/#prevent-reprocessing-with-hdfstore)

Comment: [Save and Load Machine Learning Models in Python with scikit-learn](https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-machine-learning-models-python-scikit-learn/)